# Travis CI: file from node module not found

Tags: node.js, git, mocha.js, travis-ci

I just configured Travis CI to also run my test cases. This is my `.travis.yml` file:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "0.10"
before_install: npm install -g grunt-cli
install: npm install
```

When it tries to run my test cases, it gives me the following error:

```
Error loading resource file:///home/travis/build/repo/test/node_modules/mocha/mocha.css    (203). 
Details: Error opening /home/travis/build/repo/test/node_modules/mocha/mocha.css: No such file or directory
Error loading resource file:///home/travis/build/repo/test/node_modules/mocha/mocha.js (203). 
Details: Error opening /home/travis/build/repo/test/node_modules/mocha/mocha.js: No such file or directory
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'mocha.setup('bdd')')
```

So it can not find the `mocha.css` and `mocha.js` file in the `node_modules` folder.

I'm guessing it can not find these files because they are not uploaded to Git. This is because I specified `node_modules` in my `.gitignore` file, because I do not want to upload all the modules.

What is the common way/a clean way to fix this problem?

Comment: This is not a git issue. Add `mocha` is in your package.json as a `devDepenedency` and it should be installed with `npm install`. Make sure you add the test script to your package.json

`"scripts": {
    "test": "mocha"
}`

PS: you can even remove the `instal: npm install` from your travis.yml since travis will detect this is a nodejs project and automatically run npm install, you can check your travis build logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to get out of this situation is

```
$ git add --force node_modules/mocha.css node_modules/mocha.js
$ git commit -m "Add the missing files"
$ git push
```

The "--force" option allows you to add files which are being ignored via .gitignore